Can a point be reflected through a line which is not straight?
Reflecting a point through a line (or hyperplane) is a fairly trivial bit of linear algebra, but I'm wondering  if it is meaningful to reflect a point through some other line. Say, $y=x^2$ or something wacky like $y^3=|sin(x)|+\sqrt{x}$.
To expand: I could define inversion of a point P with respect to an arbitrary curve C as, say, being reflection about the line which is tangent to C at the point nearest to P, but one would naturally want nice properties such as uniqueness and invertibility. I expect this would be equivalent to something like finding a smooth bijection between points and their reflections for a given curve.
Is this well-defined? Is it a field of study?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Inversion_in_a_circle has something for you, I think.

Did you mean reflected in the title?

Not quite a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967501/is-square-inversion-possible but raises similar issues; especially, we first have to agree what reflect through a curve means.

@spraff, one meaning of reflection can be the symmetry  of the point about the curve, is this what you mean?

One approach is to consider your curve as a subset of the complex plane, find a conformal mapping that maps your curve (or a portion of it including the point you want to reflect) to the real line, then apply the complex conjugate, and then apply the inverse conformal mapping to get the "reflection". I think this generalizes the notion of reflection across a line and inversion of a circle. I'm not sure about under what conditions this is possible and gives a unique result, though. See this question.
